# bash script to move all old files excluding directories

Tags: bash

I am new to bash script and want to create bash script that moves only  old files (but not directories) from source to destination directory as per days defined in script.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter Your Source Directory"
read soure

echo "Enter Your Destination Directory"
read destination 

echo "Enter Days"
read days

find $soure -mtime -$days -exec mv {} $destination \;
echo "Files which were $days Days old moved from $soure to $destination"
```

I am able to move files but it also retain directory structure which I don't want for specific requirement.

Comment: Debugging tips: To check if `find` is listing files properly, remove `-exec ...`. If that is correct, put `-v` option for mv.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you have filenames containing spaces, then the `mv` command will be wrong. Try this instead.

```
find $soure -mtime -$days -exec mv "{}" $destination \;
```

Some more advice may be to use the identifiers `$1`, `$2` and `$3` instead of this `read` alternative, as it is easier to use with tab completion.

Comment: You're wrong, `find`'s `{}` handles all special characters in file names without any problem. In fact, the double quotes will not even be seen by `find`, since at bash's expansion time, `"{}"` will be expanded to `{}` (without double quotes) and sent to `find` without double quotes at all (you're really confusing expansions here).

Answer (score 0):

Add `-type f` to ensure you're only moving files, not directories

```
find "$shore" -type f -mtime -$days -exec mv "{}" "$destination" \;
```